# graph-tool: How do I find vertices that fit a certain property value?

Tags: python, graph, graph-tool

I have a class Node that I set as a property for a graph using graph-tool.

```
from graph_tool.all import *

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.symbol = name
        self.named_entity = age


#create your graph object
g = Graph()

#add the property to vertex object
vprop = g.new_vertex_property("string") 

#add vertex 
v1 = g.add_vertex() #here you create a vertex
v2 = g.add_vertex() #here you create a vertex

#set the value to the vertex property
vx1 = Node("John", 15)
vx2 = Node("Sarah", 22)

v_prop[v1] = vx1
v_prop[v2] = vx2

#assign properties as a dic value
g.vertex_properties["node"]=vprop 

#add edge
g.add_edge(vertex_1,vertex_2) #add an edge 

# This does not work
find_match(g, "red")
```

How do I find vertices that match for equality on either the **name** or **age** fields for each node? The `find_match()` function seems to only work for the native types for PropertyMap.

Comment: You write a statement, or even a separate method, that expresses the compound relationship.  Does that not work for you?

Comment: Is there an example I can find for this? The docs don't seem to show one.

Comment: This is essentially a one-line Boolean expression, embedded in whatever implementation vehicle you choose.  Perhaps you need to search for a tutorial on implementing a custom `Node` method?  You haven't given any context for us to give a solution.

Comment: @Prune edited for better context, thanks

Comment: Much better.  Now, if I could find the docs that include find_match ... and maybe manage to install graph-tool to validate a solution ... then I could be of specific help.